# how to display selected div and hide others sibling div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that all unselected div will disappear and will show me only the selected card. i have different card which ids are dynamic (default++) using loop and also i added affect that when use select div it chose red border over div.

I tried different method when i click on the selected div that selected div will remain the rest div will be disappeared.

```js
//Showing border on the selected card 
$('.selects').click(function() {
  if ($('.selects.choice').length > 0) {
    $('.choice').removeClass('choice');
    $(this).addClass('choice');

  } else {
    $(this).addClass('choice');

  
  }
});
```

```css
.card{
    margin:5px;
    width:140px;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    
}

#operatorImage >img {
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
    }
    
.choice {
    border: 3px #CA0B00 solid;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.operator-card{
    
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="default-0" class="operator-card col-md-4">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12  mb-4 " >
                  <div class="card border-left-danger shadow h-100 py-2 selects">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                        <div class="col mr-2">
                          <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1" class="countryName">Afghanistan</div>
                          <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" id="operatorname">Etisalat</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto" id="operatorImage">
                            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFPfrFyKNx-0w/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=lZV1Q4xsyrvB5cocn8ht0b43KtdRrOiZ6TXU9SL2q9E"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
      
</div>

 <div id="default-2" class="operator-card col-md-4">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12  mb-4 " >
                  <div class="card border-left-danger shadow h-100 py-2 selects">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                        <div class="col mr-2">
                          <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1" class="countryName">Pakistan</div>
                          <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" id="operatorname">Telenor</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto" id="operatorImage">
                            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFPfrFyKNx-0w/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=lZV1Q4xsyrvB5cocn8ht0b43KtdRrOiZ6TXU9SL2q9E"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


<div id="default-3" class="operator-card col-md-4">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12  mb-4 " >
                  <div class="card border-left-danger shadow h-100 py-2 selects">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                        <div class="col mr-2">
                          <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1" class="countryName">Nigira</div>
                          <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" id="operatorname">MTN</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto" id="operatorImage">
                            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFPfrFyKNx-0w/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=lZV1Q4xsyrvB5cocn8ht0b43KtdRrOiZ6TXU9SL2q9E"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

</div>

<div id="default-2" class="operator-card col-md-4">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12  mb-4 " >
                  <div class="card border-left-danger shadow h-100 py-2 selects">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                        <div class="col mr-2">
                          <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1" class="countryName">Afghanistan</div>
                          <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" id="operatorname">Etisalat</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto" id="operatorImage">
                            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFPfrFyKNx-0w/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=lZV1Q4xsyrvB5cocn8ht0b43KtdRrOiZ6TXU9SL2q9E"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not understand... choice is affect on the selected div when user click and i want that other card should disappeared . if i add display:none to the choice class then it will hide the choice class not others

Comment: yes it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just toggle between siblings something like this:

```js
$('.card-body').click(function() {
  $('.card-body').not(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.card {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 140px;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#operatorImage>img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.choice {
  border: 3px #CA0B00 solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.operator-card {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="default-0" class="operator-card col-md-4">
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12  mb-4 ">
    <div class="card border-left-danger shadow h-100 py-2 selects">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
          <div class="col mr-2">
            <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1" class="countryName">Afghanistan</div>
            <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" id="operatorname">Etisalat</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto" id="operatorImage">
            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFPfrFyKNx-0w/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=lZV1Q4xsyrvB5cocn8ht0b43KtdRrOiZ6TXU9SL2q9E" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="default-2" class="operator-card col-md-4">
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12  mb-4 ">
    <div class="card border-left-danger shadow h-100 py-2 selects">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
          <div class="col mr-2">
            <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1" class="countryName">Pakistan</div>
            <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" id="operatorname">Telenor</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto" id="operatorImage">
            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQFPfrFyKNx-0w/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=lZV1Q4xsyrvB5cocn8ht0b43KtdRrOiZ6TXU9SL2q9E" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var $selects = $('.selects');

$selects.click(function() {
  $selects.not(this).removeClass('choice').hide();
  $(this).addClass('choice');
});
```

just tested and it works... but you will have to remove this important in css:

```
display: flex !important;
```

Comment: this just add choice class but other div still there i want that selected div will be displayed and sibbling will be disapeared

Comment: yes i updated my answer... you shouldn't use display: flex !important; that's why they are still visible. important overrides the css of jquery. Don't use important...